# Forked Grails VM exited with error grails 2.5.3

Tags: grails

I'm getting an error when using `run-app`. Here are my paths

```
➜ $ echo $GROOVY_HOME
/Users/anthony/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/current
➜ $ groovy --version
Groovy Version: 2.4.5 JVM: 1.8.0_25 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Mac OS X
➜ $ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home
➜ $ java -version
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)
➜ $ echo $GRAILS_HOME
/Users/anthony/.sdkman/candidates/grails/current
➜ $ grails --version
Grails version: 2.5.3
```

When I use `run-app` I get an error

```
➜ $ grails --version
Grails version: 2.5.3
| Running Grails application
objc[27433]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core
Configuring Spring Security UI ...
... finished configuring Spring Security UI
| Error Forked Grails VM exited with error
| Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/myapp
```

Comment: If you run with `--stacktrace` do you get any information about what is gong wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. It doesn't produce any stacktrace. The output is same as above.

Answer (score 0):

I got this in `Grails 2.5.3` :

```
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:19767', transport: 'socket'
Error |
Forked Grails VM exited with error

Process finished with exit code 1
```

when I commented out the constraint, and tried to save a Book with no Author

```
class Book {
  static belongsTo = [authors: Author]

  static constraints = {
    // authors nullable: true
  }
}
```

My solution was to remove `static belongsTo = [authors: Author]`